# Need to change the URL for apache localhost

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I'm new to XAMPP. I just installed XAMPP on Windows 10 and it said that port is blocked. So I changed the default port for apache from port 80 to port 8080, and now have to type HTTP://localhost:8080.
Is there a way I can change this URL to remove the port number from the URL. So it will still point to port 8080 even if I don't mention in the URL.

Comment: No. Browsers only automatically search for ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS).

Comment: Unblock port 80. Use port 80.

Comment: @Quentin how can I unblock the port? I tried to add a rule on windows firewall to allow connections for private and domain. But it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the application as administrator or, at least, using a user having admin privileges.
Ports below 1024 need higher privileges to be bound by a process.

Comment: I tried but still won't work when I run as admin.

Comment: Without the error I can't provide any support. Check the apache error log: there should be something there to better understand what's going on.